# Quotifiable Subcategory

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

In Popescu's textbook *Abelian Categories with Applications to Rings and Modules*, Theorem $3.3$ of section $4.1$ says:

> Let $\mathscr A$ be a dense subcategory of a locally small abelian category $\mathscr C$ and let $\Sigma = \Sigma_{\mathscr A}$. Then the category $\mathscr C_\Sigma$ of additive fractions of $\mathscr C$ relative to $\Sigma$ exists.

Where $\Sigma_\mathscr A$ is the system of all morphisms $s$ of $\mathscr C$ such that $\ker s$ and $\text{coker } s$ are in $\mathscr A$.

Now, in the exercises for this section, there is a question that says:

> Let $\mathscr A$ be a dense subcategory of $\mathscr C$. Give sufficient conditions (more general than in Theorem $3.3$) for the existence of the category $\mathscr C/\mathscr A$. (In this case $\mathscr A$ is called a *quotifiable subcategory*). Then the category $\mathscr C/\mathscr A$ is abelian and the canonical functor $T : \mathscr C\rightarrow \mathscr C/\mathscr A$ is exact.

My question is about what he means by the more general than in Theorem $3.3$. I don't understand what is being asked here, and I can't find any references anywhere to a quotifiable subcategory. The google search "quotifiable subcategory" returns no results.

Can anyone shed any light on this? The reason I'm interested is due to another of the exercises here.

> Let $H : \mathscr C\rightarrow \mathscr C'$ be an exact functor. Let $\ker H$ be the full subcategory containing all $X\in\mathscr C$ such that $HX = 0$. Then $\ker H$ is a dense subcategory. Furthermore, let us assume that $\ker H$ is quotifiable. Then the functor $\bar{H} : \mathscr C/\ker H \rightarrow \mathscr C'$ induced by the universal property of the quotient category is faithful.

I paraphrased that slightly, but I'm interested in it because I would like to know sufficient and necessary conditions for that induced functor to be faithful, and if quotifiable is necessary I'd like to understand what it means.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is $\mathscr C/\mathscr A$ defined?

Comment: It's defined to be the category of additive fractions $\mathscr C_\Sigma$ where $\Sigma$ is defined as above.

Comment: $\mathscr C_\Sigma$ is constructed by leaving the objects the same as in $\mathscr C$ and $\Hom(X,Y)$ is the colimit of $\Hom(X', Y/Y')$ where $X/X'$ and $Y'$ are both in $\mathscr A$

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/localizing+subcategory perhaps?

Comment: I don't think so because the next section of the textbook discusses localizing subcategories.

Comment: Now asked also on MathOverflow: [Quotifiable Subcategories](https://mathoverflow.net/q/280569).